# What is the difference between call and apply method in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have seen lot of java-script code,that uses call as well as apply methods to invoke the function.
I am little bit confuse about the exact difference and in what which one to use in what condition.

Comment: look at the mdn doc [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not jQuery things, they're JavaScript things.

They do the same thing: They call the given function using a specific value for `this` within the function call. The only difference is how you specify the arguments to pass to the function. With [`call`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4), you specify them as a series of discrete arguments (after the first one, which is what to use as `this`). With [`apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3), you specify them as an array (again after the first arg, which is what to use as `this`).

So say we have:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
   console.log("this = " + this);
   console.log("a = " + a);
   console.log("b = " + b);
   console.log("a = " + c);
}
```

These two calls do exactly the same thing:

```
foo.call("bar", 1, 2, 3);
// Note --------^--^--^--- a series of discrete args

foo.apply("bar", [1, 2, 3]);
// Note ---------^-------^-- args as an array
```

In both cases, we see:

```
this = bar
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```